# Keeping console app alive and event-driven while processes run in the background

Tags: c#, .net, process, console-application

I am trying to write a console application that acts as a "job manager" by running processes in the background.  These processes would be running JScript files with arguments passed in.  This console application will be distributed across many machines, and will pull from a centralized source (ie. database) to get jobs.  The purpose of this application is to eliminate the need for individualized batch files on all of these machines.

I am having trouble keeping the application alive.  In the code that I included, you can see in my main function that I am making an initial call to the JobManger's StartNewJobs() method.  After this initial call to this method, I'd like my application to then be event-driven, only waking up and running when a process has exited, allowing me to start a new process.  The problem I am running into is that once the main() function finishes (when the initial StartNewJobs() method finishes) the console closes and the program ends.

My question is **what is the proper way to keep my console application alive and allow it to be event-driven rather than procedural?**  I know I can probably throw in a while(true) at the end of the main function, but that seems sloppy and incorrect.

Batch file we are trying to replace:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe c:\temp\somejscriptfile.js 49f1bdd8-5e6b-40cc-92bc-eb20c237a959
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe c:\temp\somejscriptfile.js 654e3783-a1b6-43be-8027-c7d060bf131f
...
```

Program.cs:

```
using DistributedJobs.Data;
using DistributedJobs.Logging;
using DistributedJobs.Models;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling;
using System;

namespace DistributedJobs
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Get intial objects/settings
            ILogger logger = new Logger(Properties.Settings.Default.LoggingLevel, EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<ExceptionManager>());
            IDataProvider dataProvider = new SQLDataProvider();
            DMSPollingJobType availableJobTypes = DMSPollingJobType.FlatFile;
            if (Properties.Settings.Default.SupportsVPN)
            {
                availableJobTypes |= DMSPollingJobType.VPN;
            }
            String executableLocation = Properties.Settings.Default.ExecutableLocation;
            String jsLocation = Properties.Settings.Default.JSLocation;
            Int32 maxProcesses = Properties.Settings.Default.MaxProcesses;

            //Create job manager and start new processes/jobs
            DMSJobManager jobManager = new DMSJobManager(logger, dataProvider, availableJobTypes, executableLocation, jsLocation, maxProcesses);
            jobManager.StartNewJobs();
        }
    }
}
```

JobManager.cs:

```
using DistributedJobs.Models;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using DistributedJobs.Logging;

namespace DistributedJobs.Data
{
    public class JobManager
    {
        private IDataProvider DataProvider;
        private ILogger Logger;
        private Dictionary<Job, Process> RunningProcesses;
        private JobType AvailableJobTypes;
        private String ExecutableLocation;
        private String JSLocation;
        private Int32 MaxProcesses;

        public Boolean CanStartNewJob
        {
            get
            {
                Boolean canStartNewJob = false;
                if (RunningProcesses.Count < MaxProcesses)
                {
                    canStartNewJob = true;
                }
                foreach (KeyValuePair<Job, Process> entry in RunningProcesses)
                {
                    if (entry.Key.JobType != JobType.FlatFile)
                    {
                        canStartNewJob = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return canStartNewJob;
            }
        }

        public JobManager(ILogger logger, IDataProvider dataProvider, JobType availableJobTypes, String executableLocation, String jsLocation, Int32 maxProcesses)
        {
            Logger = logger;
            DataProvider = dataProvider;
            RunningProcesses = new Dictionary<Job, Process>();
            AvailableJobTypes = availableJobTypes;
            ExecutableLocation = executableLocation;
            JSLocation = jsLocation;
            MaxProcesses = maxProcesses;
        }

        public void StartNewJobs()
        {
            while (CanStartNewJob)
            {
                Job newJob = DataProvider.GetNextScheduledJob(AvailableJobTypes);
                if (newJob != null)
                {
                    Process newProcess = CreateNewProcess(newJob);
                    RunningProcesses.Add(newJob, newProcess);
                    newProcess.Start();
                }
            }
        }

        public Process CreateNewProcess(Job job)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = ExecutableLocation;
            startInfo.Arguments = JSLocation + " " + job.JobID.ToString();
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            Process retProcess = new Process()
            {
                StartInfo = startInfo,
                EnableRaisingEvents = true
            };
            retProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(JobFinished);
            return retProcess;
        }

        public void JobFinished(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Job finishedJob = null;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<Job, Process> entry in RunningProcesses)
            {
                if ((Process)sender == entry.Value)
                {
                    finishedJob = entry.Key;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (finishedJob != null)
            {
                RunningProcesses.Remove(finishedJob);
                StartNewJobs();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about a service instead of a console application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using [`Application.Run()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms157900(v=vs.110).aspx)`(System.Windows.Forms)`. This will start a standard message loop.

So at the end of your `Main` method just add a `Application.Run()`:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Get intial objects/settings
        ILogger logger = new Logger(Properties.Settings.Default.LoggingLevel, EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<ExceptionManager>());
        IDataProvider dataProvider = new SQLDataProvider();
        DMSPollingJobType availableJobTypes = DMSPollingJobType.FlatFile;
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.SupportsVPN)
        {
            availableJobTypes |= DMSPollingJobType.VPN;
        }
        String executableLocation = Properties.Settings.Default.ExecutableLocation;
        String jsLocation = Properties.Settings.Default.JSLocation;
        Int32 maxProcesses = Properties.Settings.Default.MaxProcesses;

        //Create job manager and start new processes/jobs
        DMSJobManager jobManager = new DMSJobManager(logger, dataProvider, availableJobTypes, executableLocation, jsLocation, maxProcesses);
        jobManager.StartNewJobs();

        // start message loop
        Application.Run();
    }
```